# Processing Problems (Restart Functions)

Tags: processing

I'm currently making a game and have a restart function. However, it's not working. Can someone help me? I'll show you a couple of functions that don't work.

```
// Restart

void restart() {
if (end == true) {
        fill(0);
        rect(0, 0, width, height);
        fill(255);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        textSize(125);
        text("You Lost!", width / 2, 200);
        
        fill(0);
        textAlign(CENTER);
        fill(255);
        textSize(75); 
        text("R to Restart", width / 2, height / 2 + 40);
        strokeWeight(0);
    } else {
        fill(0);
        rect(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}

// Key Pressed (Part that is not working)
if (end == true & (key == 'r' || key == 'R')) {
    background(0);
    writeWords();
    displayText();
}
```

Comment: When and where do you call restart() ?

Comment: I call restart in this: if (end == true) { restart(); }

Comment: In that case you don't need the ``if (end == true) {`` check at the beginning of your restart function. It is guaranteed. Another note about style: you can just do ``if(end)``, not ``if(end == true)``

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the 'Key Pressed' part in the function `keyPressed()` in order for Processing to detect it.

```java
void keyPressed() {
  if (end && (key == 'R' || key == 'r')) {
    background(0);
    writeWords();
    displayText();
    end = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but that didn't work

Comment: Put ``end = false`` right after the displayText() line. (Other than that, do the above; your current design will definitely not work)

Comment: I think the problem is that it will keep on showing the restart screen. I might have to edit void draw() in this case.